# Get different result on linux and windows with using Charset.forName for UTF-7

Tags: java, linux, windows

code :

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public static Charset lookup(final String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        Charset charset = Charset.forName(name); 
        if (charset != null) {
            Charset superset = map.get(charset);
            if (superset != null) {
                charset = superset;
            }
        }
        return charset;
    } catch (IllegalCharsetNameException ex) {
        log.warn("Exception caught", ex);
        return null;
    } catch (UnsupportedCharsetException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The issue happened when the 'name' is "UTF-7" for Charset.forName(name);

I always get IllegalCharsetNameException on My Linux platform.

But it looks ok on my windows platform.

Two platform have the same source code and java version

java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

I have no idea how to fix it..

Thank you !!

Comment: It is a bug on java that you can't do much about it.

Comment: But why it can run on windows???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in java that you can't do much about it

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4304013

it seems to be resolved but I'm not confident with it

Answer (score 0):

@RamonBoza has found the definitive "Bug" database entry related to this.

It is actually an RFE, requesting that UTF-7 support be added as a core feature; i.e. on all platforms.

It has been Closed with the closure code of "Won't fix".  That means that the issue *has not* been resolved, and probably won't be in the future.

The RFE comments indicate that you should look to third parties to add UTF-7 support via the standard charset API/SPI.  Googling should find a suitable implementation; e.g. you could try this open-source one: http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/

---

Whether you call this inconsistency a "bug" or not is up to you, but I'd call it a feature.  The Java documentation does not advertise UTF-7 as supported.